# Java Collection Using Date Sorting on Same Date with AM/PM

Tags: java, date

I have Date as listed below:

```
17/03/2015 09:38:39 AM
17/03/2015 10:52:26 AM
10/03/2015 08:30:56 AM
02/03/2015 09:18:10 AM
02/03/2015 09:37:23 AM
02/03/2015 11:25:01 AM
02/03/2015 11:29:00 AM
02/03/2015 11:42:38 AM
02/03/2015 12:04:39 PM
02/03/2015 12:09:05 PM
02/03/2015 01:17:09 PM
02/03/2015 01:29:08 PM
```

I want them to sort them as per below result: (Same date one should be sort by timestamp)

```
17/03/2015 10:52:26 AM
17/03/2015 09:38:39 AM
10/03/2015 08:30:56 AM
02/03/2015 01:29:08 PM
02/03/2015 01:17:09 PM
02/03/2015 12:09:05 PM
02/03/2015 12:04:39 PM
02/03/2015 11:42:38 AM
02/03/2015 11:29:00 AM
02/03/2015 11:25:01 AM
02/03/2015 09:37:23 AM
02/03/2015 09:18:10 AM
```

I tried with the code, but not getting desired output:

```
Collections.sort(listOfDate, new Comparator<SR>() {
  public int compare(SR m1, SR m2) {
    try {
      return m2.getCreatedDateActual().compareTo(m1.getCreatedD ateActual());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Output coming is:

```
17/03/2015 10:52:26 AM
17/03/2015 09:38:39 AM
10/03/2015 08:30:56 AM
02/03/2015 12:09:05 PM
02/03/2015 12:04:39 PM
02/03/2015 11:42:38 AM
02/03/2015 11:29:00 AM
02/03/2015 11:25:01 AM
02/03/2015 09:37:23 AM
02/03/2015 09:18:10 AM
02/03/2015 01:29:08 PM (Getting wrong date here)
02/03/2015 01:17:09 PM (Getting wrong date here)
```

Here is my SR class.

```
private String createdDateActual;

public void setCreatedDateActual(String createdDateActual) {
    this.createdDateActual = createdDateActual;
}

public Date getCreatedDateActual() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");

    return sdf.parse(createdDateActual);


}
```

Comment: Are you using `Date` values or `String` values?

Comment: Can you show the `getCreatedDateActual` method of the `SR` class?

Comment: post full `SR` class you you can

Comment: @user2936722: Well that format is wrong - `HH` is for a 24-hour value, not a 12-hour value. You want `hh` there. Although I'd suggest you actually move to Joda Time or java.time, both of which have thread-safe parsers which simplify things...

Comment: public void setCreatedDateActual(String createdDateActual) {
        this.createdDateActual = createdDateActual;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDateActual() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
       
        return sdf.parse(createdDateActual);
           
    }

Comment: I modified my HH to hh and now I am getting below output:                                   Tue Mar 17 10:52:26 IST 2015
Tue Mar 17 09:38:39 IST 2015
Tue Mar 10 08:30:56 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 13:29:08 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 13:17:09 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 12:09:05 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 12:04:39 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 11:42:38 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 11:29:00 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 11:25:01 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 09:37:23 IST 2015
Mon Mar 02 09:18:10 IST 2015

Comment: @user2936722: Please stop putting updates in comments. Update the question instead. It's also not at all clear what time zone these are meant to be in, which is why I've suggested using `LocalDateTime` in my answer. It would have been much better if you'd started off with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - we shouldn't have to get bits of information out of you at a time...

Comment: Jon, I will update the question. Sorry for that. I was just updating the solution, i got after changing to hh from HH.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using `HH` in your `SimpleDateFormat`, where you should be using `hh`.  The characters `HH` expect a 24-hour clock string (00-23), and the AM/PM indicator will be ignored.

Comment: Now that we've seen the parsing code, I agree that's the most immediate issue - but I still think parsing (with `hh` instead of `HH` of course) *once* into a suitable collection and then sorting would be a better outcome.

Answer (score 2):

The core problem IMO is that you *don't* have a collection of dates - you have a collection of *strings*.

I would recommend parsing those strings into a more suitable data type - I'd use `LocalDateTime` in either `java.time` or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) if you possibly can. At that point (i.e. when you've got a `List<LocalDateTime>` or something similar), just a simple sort will do the right thing.

Note that it's not just AM/PM that will cause you issues at the moment - "12:05 AM" should come before "01:00 AM" for example. If your strings were in 24 hour format instead of using AM/PM, neither of these would cause a problem - but you'd *still* be better off having data in a more natural representation.

Now that you've posted the code you're using for comparisons, you'd still have the same problem if you used *that* code to convert the strings into `LocalDateTime` values - because you're using `HH` in the parsing code instead of `hh`. The `HH` format specifier is for 24-hour values, and is very rarely appropriate in conjunction with `a` (the AM/PM specifier). Instead, you should use `hh` which is in the range 01-12.

As a separate aside, it's *very* odd to have a property where the set method takes one type, but the get method returns something totally different (`String` and `Date` in your case respectively). I'd encourage you to be consistent.

Comment: I am having date with AM/PM only, not in 24 hours format,. Can I get the desired result.

Comment: @user2936722: Yes, I've already told you how - parse the values into a more suitable collection.